# ¿Cómo ejecutar una tarea periódicamente a demanda usando Celery?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

Estoy usando [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) en mi aplicación para poder procesar en tiempo real algunos datos estadísticos.

Esta es una tarea de prueba que consume algunos datos mediante la llamada a un procedimiento almacenado y finalmente publicarlos en una vista en Django:

```
@app.task
def broadcast_dashboard():
    data = {}
    params = [
        1, '2015-12-23', '1000089'
    ]
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('dashboard_kardexlote', params)
    kardex = dictfetchall(cursor)
    data['kardex'] = sorted(kardex, key=lambda r: r['lote'], reverse=True)
    publish_data(
        channel='dashboard',
        data=data
    )
    cursor.close()
```

Estoy usando [`entries`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries) con `celery beat` y en mi configuración de Django tengo, entre otras cosas, lo siguiente:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'dashboard-schedule': {
        'task': 'tasks.broadcast_dashboard',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1),
    },
}
```

Luego, si ejecuto `celery` con la opción `-B` para `celery beat`:

```
$ celery -A tasks worker -B --loglevel=info
```

Funciona perfecto, obtengo la información en tiempo real y actualizada al segundo en mi vista lo cual me permite mostrar algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que ahora necesito que los parámetros de la tarea (`params`) sean seleccionados por el usuario y asumo (corríjanme si me equivoco) que usar `celery beat` ya no tendría sentido. Lo que necesito es saber si es posible ejecutar la tarea a demanda, de acuerdo a la información que el usuario seleccione en un formulario.

Se que puedo llamar a la tarea usando [`apply_async`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html?highlight=apply_async#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) y pasarle los parámetros:

```
broadcast_dashboard.apply_async(kwargs={'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

Pero esto solo lo ejecuta una vez y lo que quiero es que se ejecute periódicamente cada segundo. ¿Es posible hacer esto?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, yo estoy intentando hacer una aplicación en tiempo real con django y djceley y la verdad prácticamente estoy iniciando, yo le di solución a algo como lo que plantea la pregunta de la siguiente forma:
En mi view.py

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    periodic_task = PeriodicTask(
        name= form.cleaned_data['nombre'],
        task=form.cleaned_data['tarea'],
        interval = form.cleaned_data['intervalo'],
        crontab=form.cleaned_data['fecha_inicio'],
          )      
    periodic_task.save()
    return        super(ProgramarActividadView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Escribí directamente en la base de datos del periodictask y el resultado fue exitoso. Duda: porque en las versiones actuales no se usa djcelery? yo lo instale hace 10 dias :(

Comment: Tengo que entendido que ahora se llama django-celery, o algo así, y tiene integración con el admin de django. Yo tengo que usarlo para wagtail. Han tenido avances?

Answer (score 0):

Pasa `params` como argumentos en tu método `broadcast_dashboard()`, y luego puedes pasarle esos argumentos desde `localhost/admin/djcelery/periodictask/add/` y así programar la `periodictask` desde el admin django y ya no desde el `settings`;

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: En las versiones actuales ya no se usa `djcelery`, no lo estoy usando